# Window could not service on the local computer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am facing issue on starting services find the below attachment. I am using Dot net7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Atwi.png)

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
          ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
          var result = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
          result.Run();
      
  }
  public static Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
     .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
     {
         webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
         webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
         {
             options.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 8989, configure =>
             {
                 configure.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
                 configure.UseHttps(opt => opt.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13);
             });
         });

     }).UseWindowsService(sn => sn.ServiceName = "Test Service");`
```

I am trying run in cmd prompt using cmd line sc create "Test Service" binPath ="D:\Test.exe"

Comment: Well your service is crashing. Add some exception handling to see what s going on

Comment: check in event viewer, you should get the exception event log from there, that should be helpful to point out the problem

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code to generate a service. Maybe you have the same problem.

EventViewer-System
[image]

EventViewer-Application
[image]

Well, I didn't solve this problem by suggested commands. But in .net7 you could write the code in another way which works.
Package`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsService`
program.cs

```
using System.Security.Authentication;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
        {
            serverOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
            });
        });

        builder.Services.AddWindowsService();

        var app = builder.Build();

        app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

appsettings.json  (configure the ports and select a certificate here)

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:8988"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:8989",
        "Certificate": {
          "Subject": "localhost",
          "Store": "My",
          "Location": "LocalMachine",
          "AllowInvalid": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

publish and create service.
`sc create TestService4 binPath=E:\TESTS\TestService\TestService\bin\Release\net7.0\publish\TestService.exe`

Start and Test
[image]

Select a certificate from subject
[image]
)

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#replace-the-default-certificate-from-configuration